# Question about meaning and definition of zero map

Tags: functional-analysis

For the following question:

Let $X$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $f:X\rightarrow K$ be linear.  Show that $f(X)=K$ of and only if $f$ is not the zero map.

I would like some clarification that if $f$ is not the zero map, does it mean that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in X$ including $x=0$.   I learned that in linear algebra, for linear maps, $f $ is one to one and onto if and only if the dimension of $f's$ null space is zero.  If it is the case that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$, and including $x=0$, then does it mean that $f$ is not one to one, but still can be onto in the case of even infinite dimensional vector spaces?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f$ is the zero map if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$. So $f$ is not the zero map if $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in X$ (this is logic - if it is not true that all flowers are red, it means that there exists a flower which is not red (while you wrote that all flowers are not red - not the same)).

Comment: That's correct. The zero map is constant and has the value $0$. You just need to find one $x$ such that  $f(x)=k$ with $k \neq 0$ to show it's non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

The zero map $X\to K$ is the function that takes everything to $0$, i.e. $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$. If $f$ is not this function, i.e. if there exists any $x\in X$ so that $f(x)\neq0$, then it is not the zero map. Note that $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$ and hence $f(0)=0$ whenever $f$ is linear, so it is not possible for a linear map to satisfy $f(x)\neq0$ for all $x$.

Comment: if $f$ is not the zero map, the direct image of $f$ can still be onto, but it can't be one to one.  If that is the case, how do I show it for the case of infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @SethMai Obviously $f(X)=K$ implies that $f$ is nonzero. Now the image of any linear map is a subspace of its codomain, so if $f$ is nonzero, then $\operatorname{im}f$ is a nontrivial subspace of $K$. But $K$ is a field, so...?

Comment: $K$ is a field of dimension one so, so it is necessarily onto.  Is that correct?

Comment: @SethMai yes, $K$ is a vector space of dimension $1$ over itself. So since the dimension of the image is nonzero and $\leq1$, it has to be $1$ and hence the image is the whole field.

Comment: usually in math, when we have a linear map where the codomain is a field, it is usually understood to have dimension one, unless if it is say a finite field, in that case, it would be specifically stated as finite field instead of just being "field" to stand for finite field.

Comment: @SethMai I don't know what you're saying. Dimensionality is a notion applied to vector spaces over a fixed field, and so the dimension of a field $K$ treated as a vector space over itself is $1$. This applies regardless of whether or not $K$ is finite.